# Remove specific table with jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to remove a table but I can't. How can I remove it? I have tried the code below, but that doesn't work.

```
Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
final Elements elements = doc2.select("div.postarea");
doc2.select("div table").remove();
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with jsoup, but does `select("div table")` actually select the table? Shouldn't it just be `select("table")` or maybe `select("div\table")`?

Comment: Can you post a sample HTML? From the inspector, right click > select outer html.  It will be helpful to select the low level table if we understand what the parent tags are.  As it is, the HTML markup is too broad to target it without it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code ise running:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
                    final Elements elements = doc.select("div.postarea");
                    elements.last().select("table ul").remove();
```